# Solve the following integral

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

How

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin2x\cos nxdx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin2x\cos nxdx\right]=\frac{-2}{\pi}\frac{1+\cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})}{n^2-4}$$

$n=1,2,3,\ldots$

??

#### My Attempt

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin2x\cos nxdx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin2x\cos nxdx\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}[\sin(n+2)x-sin(n-2)x]dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}[\sin(n+2)x-sin(n-2)x]dx\right)$$
$$=\frac{5}{\pi(n^2-4)}$$

As,
$$\int\sin(n+2)xdx=\frac{-\cos(n+2)x}{(n+2)}+c$$

And

$\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2})=0;\quad\cos(-\pi)=-1;\quad\cos(\pi)=-1;\quad\cos(0)=1$

Comment: I really don't understand the numerator of $5$.  Doesn't the numerator vary with $n$?

Comment: @Doc The $5$ of numerator occurred from after putting the values of $\cos$ at several points that i mentioned in the last line. But somehow i am incorrect so that i couldn't able to reach the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{-\pi}^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin[(n+2)x]-sin[(n-2)x]dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin[(n+2)]x-sin[(n-2)x]dx$$

$$=-\frac{\cos[(n+2)\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)]}{(n+2)}+\frac{\cos[(n-2)\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)]}{(n-2)}+\frac{\cos[(n+2)(-\pi)]}{(n+2)}-\frac{\cos[(n-2)(-\pi)]}{(n-2)}-\frac{\cos[(n+2)\pi]}{(n+2)}+\frac{\cos[(n-2)\pi]}{(n-2)}+\frac{\cos[(n+2)0]}{(n+2)}-\frac{\cos[(n-2)0]}{(n-2)}$$

Because $\cos(x)$ is even we can cancel all the terms with $\pi$ in them leaving us with

$$-\frac{\cos[(n+2)\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)]}{(n+2)}+\frac{\cos[(n-2)\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)]}{(n-2)}+\frac{\cos[(n+2)0]}{(n+2)}-\frac{\cos[(n-2)0]}{(n-2)}$$

$$=-\frac{\cos[(n+2)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)]}{(n+2)}+\frac{\cos[(n+2)\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)]}{(n-2)}+\frac{1}{(n+2)}-\frac{1}{(n-2)}$$

$$=-\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}+\pi\right)}{(n+2)}+\frac{\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}+\pi\right)}{(n-2)}+\frac{-4}{(n^{2}-4)}$$

$$=-\frac{-\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{(n+2)}+\frac{-\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{(n-2)}+\frac{-4}{(n^{2}-4)}$$

$$=\frac{-4\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)}{(n^{2}-4)}+\frac{-4}{(n^{2}-4)}=\frac{-4\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\right)}{(n^{2}-4)}$$

Multiplying through by the $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ that I left off at the beginning will get you your result.

Side note -- I personally would have used integration by parts on this one.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about the simplifications I made.  I used some properties of $\cos(x)$ without mention.

Comment: Why can't i put the value $0$ in the terms of $\cos$ where it contains $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ since if $n$ is integer $\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}=0$

Comment: Because if $n=2$ we have $\cos(\pi)$ which is $-1$.  For $n=4$ we have $\cos(2\pi)=1$ and so on.

Comment: Now it is clear . Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome!